# multiple custom fields using xml in joomla

Tags: jquery, xml, joomla

I need to create some custom fields using xml in a module in joomla 3.0. 
I did somethething like this, shown below.
my mod_category.xml file code for fields is :

```
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="protection" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_careercategory/include/" label="tagelement">
    <field name="headerTitle" type="text" default="" label="HEADER_TITLE" description="HEADER_TITLE_DESC"/>
    <field name="Title" type="tagelements" label="TITLE" id="Title"/>
</fieldset>
</fields>
```

and my tagelements.php code is :

```
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldTagElements extends JFormField
{
    protected $type = 'tagelements'; //the form field type

 protected function getInput()
 {

     return '<input type="text" name="'.$this->name.'" id="'.$this->id.'" label="Title"/><br />'.
        '<input type="text" name="Link" id="Link" label="Link"/><br />'.
        '<input type="text" name="Order" id="order" label="order"/><br />'.
        '<input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="addmore" value="Add more">
         <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove" />';               


 }
```

I have two buttons, add and remove, which, using jQuery will add more of these fields when clicked. The fields will be removed when the remove button is clicked.

When I am running this code 4 text boxes are displayed and two buttons. But when I save the form only the value of the first textbox is stored in the database.

I want all of the fields to be saved. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please show your jQuery code that you're using to add/remove fields

Comment: How are you planning on storing dynamically created fields in a static database? One way is to use json to encode the fields and store them in a properties field in the database

Comment: `$this->name` has a string like **jform**, so you need to add it manually/programmatically to the name of **Link** and **Order** elements, too. It becomes say `<input type="text" name="jform[Link]" id="jform_Link" label="Link"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe custom form fields are only designed to create a single form field, so it won't be expecting the subsequent fields when the form is saved.

What probably would work would be to have your main field ( the one with the name "$this->name" ) be a hidden field, which your jquery then populates with the other data on submit (probably in a json format).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data for all three available server side, they really should be three separate text fields within your form XML definition file.  Your custom field simply groups three standard text field into one, but as a previous poster noted, custom fields in Joomla are geared towards handling one field.

The "best" solution depends on what you want to do with the data and where is it being done in the code server side.